# will Environment.Special.LocalApplicationData be deleted when uninstalling the app in iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, special-folders

In iOS, I am saving the downloaded images in Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData and referring the images from that location as image source. Will the images saved in that location will be deleted when uninstalling the application in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be deleted as it will be saved in the application's sandbox. If you uninstall the app the application's sandbox will also be deleted.